# CRA lint multiple directories

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

I would like for my CRA to run lint on save for all directories in my project.  It currently only lints the `/react` directory.  I want it to lint my `/common` directory as well.  Is there a way to configure this so that CRA runs the lint on save?

I can add a script to run lint on that dir once when it first compiles, but I can't figure out how to have it run on save.  Both have directories have an `.eslintrc.json` file and VSCode sees this in the `/common` directory.

**My project**

```
-package.json
  -react
    package.json
    -src/
  -common
    package.json
    -src/
```

**Top-level package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:web": "concurrently \"cd backend && npm run start:dev\" \"cd react && npm start\"",
```

**/react/package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start"
```